# Convert entered number to Only 2 decimal in the Excel sheet in C# using Math.Round Function

Tags: c#

The Entered number in excel is converting to decimals but its giving so many decimal, want only 2 decimal places

```html
 var selectedDate = ApplicationGlobals.SelectedProjectGroupDetails.SelectedDate.StartDate();
                var startDate = DateTime.Now.StartDate();

                var editableColumns = _canMaintainProjectDemandByProjectGroup ? (startDate.Year - selectedDate.Year) * 12 + startDate.Month - selectedDate.Month : _projectDemandByProjectGroupDataTable.Columns.Count;

                var projectDemandByProjectGroupSpreadSheetScript = string.Format(sb.ToString(), _spreadSheetId, _projectDemandByProjectGroupDataTable.Rows.Count + 1,
                    _projectDemandByProjectGroupDataTable.Columns.Count, _spreadSheetName, _columnAttributes, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_projectDemandByProjectGroupDataTable),
                    _columnFields, _hiddenColumns, _fixedColumns, ApplicationGlobals.ActualsColumns, editableColumns);

                var minifier = new Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.Minifier();
                return string.Format("<script>{0}</script>", minifier.MinifyJavaScript(projectDemandByProjectGroupSpreadSheetScript));
```

The Entered number in excel is converting to decimals but its giving so many decimal, want only 2 decimal places

```
toInt = function(num) 
{
    return Math.round(num * Math.Pow(10,decimals));
}

if(employeeAddInfo != null)
{
    var resource = string.Format("{0} - {1}", employee.FullName, employee.EmpNo);
    var dataRow = new List<object> { x.EmployeeNumber, false, employee.DepartmentIdNo, employee.Department, resource, employee.FullName, x.EmployeeNumber, employeeAddInfo.Skill, employeeAddInfo.Rate };

    financialCalendarList.ForEach(a =>
    {
        dynamic displayValue = null;
        if (financialCalendarList.IndexOf(a) < ApplicationGlobals.ActualsColumns)
        {
            var totalQuantity = actualsListForEmployeeNotExistsInProjectDemand
                .Where(y => y.EmployeeNumber == x.EmployeeNumber)
                .Where(y => y.FiscalYear == a.Year).Where(y => y.FiscalPeriod == a.Month)
                .Sum(y => y.Quantity);

            displayValue = ApplicationGlobals.IsDisplayInEp ? Math.Round(totalQuantity / a.WorkingHours, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero) : totalQuantity;

        }
        dataRow.Add(displayValue == null ? 0 : string.Format("{0}({1})", displayValue, displayValue.ToString("F")));
    });
    dataTable.Rows.Add(dataRow.ToArray());
}
```

Comment: the function return to many decimals or the value in the excel itself have to many decimals?

Comment: the function is returning many decimals

Comment: you can do is `yourdecimalVal.ToString("c2");`?

Comment: The number of decimals shown in an Excel cell depends on the cell's format. If you want it to display with only two decimals a) *DON'T* convert it to text and b) set the number of digits you want in the Excel sheet itself

Comment: @MVS btw there's no Excel code here. No attempt to round numbers and set the values of fields. Are you trying to *fake* an Excel file by dumping a DataTable into CSV or HTML? Why not create a *real* Excel sheet with a library like [EPPlus](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus)? You can load a list of strongly-typed objects into a real sheet with a simple call to `sheet.LoadFromCollection(someCollection);`